# Can I Improve Performance on Bloated System Tables?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

**Background:**
I have numerous databases with a large number of VIEW's, and an extremely large number of SYNONYM's.  For example, one db has more than 10k VIEW's and 2+ million SYNONYM's.

**General Problem:**
Queries involving `sys.objects` (and system tables in general) tend to be slow.  Queries involving `sys.synonyms` are glacial.  I am wondering what I can do to improve performance.

**Specific Example**
This command is run by a third party tool.  It is slow in both the app, and in SSMS:

```
exec sp_tables_rowset;2 NULL,NULL
```

**My Question**:
How can I make this run faster?

**What I've Tried**:
If I `SET STATISTICS IO ON` I get this output:

> (2201538 row(s) affected)
> Table 'sysobjrdb'. Scan count 1, logical
>   reads 28, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0,
>   lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0. 
> Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan
>   count 1, logical reads 53926, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0,
>   lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

I have been able to update statistics on the underlying system tables.  This has worked in my SQL 2008 R2 or newer environments:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysobjrdb WITH FULLSCAN
UPDATE STATISTICS sys.sysschobjs WITH FULLSCAN
```

I have also been able to perform index maintenance.  This works in my SQL 2012 or newer environments.  For instance running `sp_help 'sys.sysschobjs'` identifies the indexes on the table, and from there I create and run these commands:

```
ALTER INDEX clst ON sys.sysschobjs REORGANIZE
ALTER INDEX nc1 ON sys.sysschobjs REORGANIZE
ALTER INDEX nc2 ON sys.sysschobjs REORGANIZE
ALTER INDEX nc3 ON sys.sysschobjs REORGANIZE
```

Updating stats and reorganizing indexes helps, but not by much.

Comment: Ouch. I'm guessing you're doing some messed up type of multi tenant, keeping everyone's data in the same tables & filtering it with views & using synonyms to name them after the base object, on a  large scale? Either way, I feel for you

Comment: Multi tenant?  Actually, no. It isn't.  Pretty messed up, right?  FWIW, it's my understanding that for every application user, there are 5 SYNONYMs created for every table.  Lucky me.

Comment: Does removing permissions to some of those objects increase performance (so that there is less of them to potentially use?) I dont know if that is even an option on a user level.

Comment: It would be interesting to see an execution plan on this. maybe you could post one from sql sentry plan explorer to https://answers.sqlperformance.com/ and link to it, unless there is a way to embed this here as well.  I'd be interesting in looking at it

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already done so, you could gain performance by moving the primary data file to a separate set of spindles from the rest of the data (see [Files and Filegroups Architecture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316(v=sql.105).aspx) and [SQL Server: filegroup for system tables only?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/sql-server-filegroup-for-system-tables-only)).

Comment: I think that this is sound advice, however, it would be negated on impacting much if IO setup is not a standard physical server with attached disks, for instance virtual instance with SAN, or SSD drives would minimize the noticeable impact of separating primary data files to a different location, right?

Comment: If you have control of the hardware (i.e. you're not being hosted by a third party), you can have different sets of spindles in a SAN (e.g. two or more separate RAID-10 volumes). If You're using (or hosted) with SSDs, then there are no spindles, and IO would be limited mainly by whatever is the bottleneck between the drives and the motherboard (i.e. SATA, RAID, or NIC card, cabling, routers/switches, SAN, SSDs speed), so you wouldn't gain anything by separating the files in that case.